# Multiple Leaflet using Angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, leaflet

I am trying to make application where different user have different set of map. In order to accomplish this, I intend to use Leaflet and AngularJS. The plan is, using ng-repeat, AngularJS will be able to call multiple Leaflet map, different for each user.

This is my html snippet:

```
<div class="row" style="text-align:center"><!-- /.row -->
    <!-- /.map-col -->
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12" ng-repeat="map in maps">
        <h2>Asu</h2>
        <div id="leaflets[{{$index}}]" style="height:300px"></div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

The javascript code:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < $scope.maps.length; i++ ) { 
  try{
    $scope.leaflets[i] = L.map('leaflets[' + i + ']', {
      maxZoom: 4,
      minZoom: 1,
      crs: L.CRS.Simple
    }).setView([0, 0], 1);
    // dimensions of the image
    var w = 1080,
    h = 855,
    imageUrl = $scope.maps[i].url;
    var southWest = $scope.leaflets[i].unproject([0, h], $scope.leaflets[i].getMaxZoom()-1);
    var northEast = $scope.leaflets[i].unproject([w, 0], $scope.leaflets[i].getMaxZoom()-1);
    var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
    L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, bounds).addTo($scope.leaflets[i]);
    // tell leaflet that the map is exactly as big as the image
    $scope.leaflets[i].setMaxBounds(bounds);
    var dataPoints = $scope.maps[i].dataPoints;
    var heat = L.heatLayer(dataPoints, {
      radius: 40, maxZoom: 4
    }).addTo($scope.leaflets[i]);
  }
  catch(err) {

  }
}
```

When I tried writing the div id manually, e.g.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12" ng-repeat="map in maps">
    <h2>Asu</h2>
    <div id="leaflets[0]" style="height:300px"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12" ng-repeat="map in maps">
    <h2>Asu</h2>
    <div id="leaflets[1]" style="height:300px"></div>
</div>
```

It is displayed perfectly. In both case, when I try to "Inspect Element" in Chrome,

P.S. the error in ms javascript when using

Anybody have similar problem or have idea to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because the javascript is executed while the HTML is still being rendered. This cause the javascript code cannot find the  with corresponding id.

I use $timeout service in AngularJS to execute the JS code after HTML finished rendering:

The HTML is still the same:

```
<div class="panel-body no-padding">
    <div class="row" style="text-align:center"><!-- /.row -->
    <!-- /.map-col -->
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12" ng-repeat="map in maps">
            <h2>{{map.title}}</h2>
            <div id="leaflets[{{$index}}]" style="height:300px"></div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.row -->
</div><!-- /.panel-body -->
```

The JS now use timeout:

```
.controller('EngCtrl', function ($timeout, $scope, $location, $http, $templateCache, $filter) {

...
...

var initMap = function () {
  for ( var i = 0; i < $scope.maps.length; i++ ) { 
    try{
      $scope.leaflets[i] = L.map('leaflets[' + i + ']', {
        maxZoom: 4,
        minZoom: 1,
        crs: L.CRS.Simple
      }).setView([0, 0], 1);
      // dimensions of the image
      var w = 1080,
      h = 855,
      imageUrl = $scope.maps[i].url;
      var southWest = $scope.leaflets[i].unproject([0, h], $scope.leaflets[i].getMaxZoom()-1);
      var northEast = $scope.leaflets[i].unproject([w, 0], $scope.leaflets[i].getMaxZoom()-1);
      var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
      L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, bounds).addTo($scope.leaflets[i]);
      // tell leaflet that the map is exactly as big as the image
      $scope.leaflets[i].setMaxBounds(bounds);
      var dataPoints = $scope.maps[i].dataPoints;
      var heat = L.heatLayer(dataPoints, {
        radius: 40, maxZoom: 4
      }).addTo($scope.leaflets[i]);
    }
    catch(err) {
    }
  }
}

$timeout(initMap, 0);
```